# Persistent Threads in Swift GCD

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am completely new to Swift GCD.Could someone explain the idea of a background threads in GCD?
I would like to continuously fetch sensor data using a background thread(which should never be killed) and run UI and other things in the main thread(assuming the app is running in the foreground). Currently, I tried something like this (in the 'application' function of AppDelegate.swift):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0)) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            SensorCollection.sensorActivate(CMMotionManager())
        }
}
```

SensorCollection : A sensor collection class I created.
sensorActivate : A class function.
CMMotionManager() : The in-built swift motion manager.

Comment: What problem are you seeing? The above code says to launch-in-the-background a task to launch-on-the-main-thread a call to `sensorActivate()`. That doesn't seem to have any relationship to the question you asked. Have you started by reading over the Concurrency Programming Guide that introduces all of this? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091

Comment: Separately from @RobNapier's comment, it's possibly also worth saying that if you want to create and own a thread then you should just do that via `NSThread`. Don't just take one of the threads out of the GCD thread pool. There's only a small number of those.

Comment: "Could someone explain the idea of a background threads in GCD" http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html

Comment: @Tommy iOS developers should never use `NSThread` (I was going to say "almost never" but I cannot think of a single case where it is the right tool today). You're correct that you shouldn't try to "take a GCD thread" or anything like that. You have to think about the problem in a different way and let GCD manage the threads itself.

Comment: I think I will just remove the threading completely.Apparently its not required for sensor data collection in Swift.My concepts of Swift are shaky at best.

Comment: @RobNapier absolutely; the correct edit to my comment would be to switch 'if you want' to 'if you need' and add the caveat that: you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to continuously fetch sensor data using a background thread

That is what built-in CMMotionManager calls all let you do, so simply use them and stop trying to manage the threads yourself.

For example, `startGyroUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:` lets you specify a queue. `startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:` lets you specify a queue. And so on.

So simply create a queue, store it in a property, and specify that queue when you start updating. Problem solved. Don't make this more complicated than it has to be by adding your own threading when you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you.I will do as you said.I honestly don't know much about Swift.I was just trying out something to learn concepts of this language.